# Validating with rang only if another field is a certain value for validation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If there was food and intake in my model. intake can only be more than 0 when food is not 0. 
Is there any build in validation for this? like a validation for RangeIf just like there is RequiredIf?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ConstantMessages.Please_enter + "food")]
public string food { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = ConstantMessages.Please_enter + "intake")]
public string intake { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can add custom validations!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to create a **Model Validation Attribute**;

Assuming your model class is:

```
[NoZeroIntakeOnFood]
public class ModelClass
{
    public string food{ get; set; }
    public string intake { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a sample model-level validation (rather than attribute-level):

```
public class NoZeroIntakeOnFoodAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    public NoZeroIntakeOnFoodAttribute() 
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Intake cannot be zero, when food has value";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) 
    {
        ModelClass model = value as ModelClass;
        if (model?.food != null ) 
        {
           // the intake needs to be more than zero
           if( Convert.ToInt32(model.intake) > 0)
               return true;
           else return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put the `NoZeroIntakeOnFood` on your model class.
Of course, grab the above code and tweak it to your needs.

Hope this helped. :)

--
Here, we assumed you're on MVC 5 .Net Framework. If you're using Asp.Net Core MVC, have a look on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes) for better adaptation.

Comment: i checked on the validationAttributte and it seems that custom attributte does not validate on same page and would pass isvalid false to controller, but remote attribute will validate on same page. but the problem i how can i use the same remote attributte if i have intake1 and intake2. because the additionalfield is using the same name from model as parameter.

Comment: Please explain why custom attribute doesn't validate on the same page. Make sure the form data you submit, exactly corresponds to your class model. A better idea can be enabling Client-Side validation and putting break-point on the custom validator.

Comment: Secondly, I recommend you keep away from Remote validation unless there's a good reason for it. Because validation action method will be called when the user first submits the form and then again each time he or she
edits the data. In essence, every keystroke will lead to a call to the server. For some applications, this can be a significant number
of requests and must be taken into account when specifying the server capacity and bandwidth that an application requires in
production.

Comment: i wanted a client side validation. but more dynamic. can custom attribute do that?

Comment: Sure, it can. Just need to enable it. see this link: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/enable-client-side-valiation-in-mvc